# Order SQL Server Query by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with SQL server 2008R2. I have a query that returns the below dataset:

```
ID FirstName LastName  Relation

1  Sam       Ali   Employee
1  Maya      Ali   Dependent
2  Nadia     Amle  Employee
1  Sue       Ibram  Dependent
3  Saher     Jacobs  Employee
2  Alie      Salem   Dependent
```

I want the query results this way below:

ID FirstName LastName Relation
1 Sam Ali Employee
1 Maya Ali Dependent
1 Sue Ibram Dependent
2 Nadia Amle Employee
2 Alie Salem Dependent
4 Joe Davis  Employee
3 Saher Jacobs Employee

Now the requirements:
1. Group by ID so that employees and dependents that have the same ID are next to each other.
2. Order Column LastName by A-Z.

Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: It's highly recommended to have a primary key for every table. You obviously don't have one here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self-join so you can get the employee associated with each dependent, and order by that.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Relation, t2.LastName AS EmployeeName
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.Relation = "Employee"
ORDER BY EmployeeName, t1.ID, t1.LastName
```

Including `t1.ID` in the ordering is in case there are two employees with the same last name. This ensures that all the people in that group stay together in the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it now. Do you want to order each group by the lowest last name in the group?

Comment: Why doesn't my answer do what you want? It keeps all the employees and dependents with the same ID together, and orders by last name within those groups.

Comment: I think you need to explain why ID 4 comes before ID 3.

Comment: Because ID 4 LastName Value precedes ID 3 LastName Value when ordering A-Z.

Answer (score 1):

You can use barmer answer like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID, LastName
```

Comment: The above doesn't work, please look at edited Question

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
ORDER BY ID, LastName
```

You can order multiple columns, and the order which you specify them is the precedence each has. So in this case it reads like "Order by ID first, and then LastName next"

UPDATE

`ORDER BY ID, LastName, FirstName`

This should get you what you're after.

Comment: @user3186783 The new ordering doesn't make sense, it's not ordered by ID anymore, ID 3 appears below ID 4